# Taking NSArray and displaying as Integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

Got a questions so I'm storing some data into an array from some json data the array is called stations and this is what it return when i log it in the function where I'm trying to print it.

```
self.stations = (
   24,
   33,
   8,
   41,
   60,
   73,
   49,
   12
)
```

i want to print this data in the detail of the label so currently I have

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"( 0 / %@)  Computers Available", self.stations];
```

But when I run it the only thing that shows in the detail area of the label is ( 0 /

then it repeats that for all the cells. How do I got about turning this array into integers? i'm assuming this is happening because it is an ID but how do i take that and turn it into Ints? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Down voters, please explain why you're down voting what appears to be a legitimate question.

Comment: Who knows, I know it was a simple answers but sometimes you just need another pair of eyes. Sorry for wasting your time down voters but this is the only way I can get better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show one value per cell then you probably want something like:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"( 0 / %@)  Computers Available", self.stations[indexPath.row]];
```

You are trying to show the entire array in each cell.

Comment: Ugh I feel stupid right now, thanks kind stranger sorry for my lack of paying attention.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to close the question by accepting the answer after the required delay.